# why do we use multiple pods in a kubernetes deployment

Tags: kubernetes

basically i'm new to kubernetes environment

i don't know why we needd to create multiple ReplicaSet of a same pod in a deplyment

some of the documentation here https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicaset/

Comment: load balancing, High availability.(not limited to these reasons)

Comment: You don't need to create ReplicaSets at all and can mostly ignore them.

Comment: @DavidMaze yes but their must be a region for creating multiple pods. is it going to make my application faster and if it is then how??

Comment: You typically use a [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/), which will run as many copies of the application (Pods) as you specify `replicas:`.  Requests via the matching [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) will be load-balanced between the Pods.  If your application isn't otherwise restricted (for example by database bandwidth) and you need the capacity then this could make it faster, but it doesn't automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use multiple pods out of many reasons:

- Split the load between more machines (cloud paradigm of many small instead of few
  bigs) which leads to:
- Great scaling
- Great redundancy
  The replica set is a solid way of doing it, as you tell Kubernetes what you want.

Answer (score 2):

This is not anything special to kubernetes, the concept of *scaling* has been around much earlier, but before kubernetes (or any other orchestration tool), it was much harder to achieve. I still remember the way we used to deploy *many* instances of an application and load balance requests... it was a tiny little nightmare compare to modern tools that we have.

So the reasons to have many instances of the same application are (but not limited to): load balancing, high availability, better handling of request spikes, failover (in some sense), etc.